# wso2/wso2ei-integrator:6.5.0-centos on OpenShift

Tags: wso2, openshift

During installation wso2 / wso2ei-integrator: 6.5.0-centos on OpenShift error / bin / sh appears: /home/wso2carbon/init.sh: Permission denied.
When changing permissions, I have an error: chmod: changing permissions of '/ home / wso2caarbon /': Operation not permitted

Does anyone know how to install WSO2 enterprise integrator on Openshift?

thanks

Comment: Looks like it expects to run as `root`. By default an OpenShift cluster will run stuff as an assigned user ID. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html and https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Answer (score 0):

> chmod: changing permissions of '/ home / wso2caarbon /': Operation not permitted 
>   Looks like it expects to run as root. By default an OpenShift cluster will run stuff as an assigned user ID

Indeed Graham is right, if you see the startup script, it tries to chmod the some directories (based on the version used). What we've done - we did that in the Dockerfile, so no chmod is executed in the initialization script. Just make sure any mounted persistent filesystem will have permission to for the runtime user.

Actually - which version (github ref of the EI dockerfile) are you using? Seeing the [current version](https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei/blob/master/dockerfiles/centos/integrator/init.sh) I see there's no chmod in the init.sh now